# In a text file replace patterns with other patterns according to another file

Tags: bash, awk

### Example 1

Let's say I have in `file1.txt` this:

```
line 1
line 45
line 3
line 2
line 24
line 1
```

And in `file2.txt` this instead:

```
line 1,WWWW
line 2,EEE
line 3,RRR
```

What I would like is something that looks into `file2.txt`, search all the terms before the `,` and replace them with the terms after the `,` in `file1.txt`. I want all the lines not present in `file2.txt` to be ignored, the order preserved.

So, the expected output should be, `file1.txt`:

```
WWW
line 45
RRR
EEE
line 24
WWW
```

### Example 2

Now, another example to a different need:
`file1.txt`:

```
line1 1
line22 78
line32 65
line3 3
line2 2    
line2 2
```

`file2.txt`:

```
line1 1,SONG1 playing: X | NAME1
line2 2,SONG2 playing: Y | NAME2
line3 3,SONG3 playing: Z | NAME3
```

Expected output should be:

```
SONG1 playing: X | NAME1
line22 78
line32 65
SONG3 playing: Z | NAME3
SONG2 playing: Y | NAME2
SONG2 playing: Y | NAME2
```

And keep in mind that the script contains hundreds and hundreds of lines (5+ MB worth of text).

Comment: You want to [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) the files on the first field and output the second field from the second fie.

Comment: How can I achieve that? `join -t , file1.txt file2.txt` gave `line 1,WWW` etc... How can I replace the first field with the second one? The page and help weren't clear enough.

Comment: Oh and keep in mind that the files aren't exclusively based on `line 1` etc.. so a more specific way to only replace the first field with the second file of `file2.txt` but on the `file1.txt` would be a bless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** since OP added more scenario in question to adding this code to cover that now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{val=$1;$1="";sub(/^ +/,"");a[val]=$0;next}  $0 in a{$0=a[$0]} 1' FS=',' file2.txt FS=' ' file1.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
SONG1 playing: X | NAME1
line22 78
line32 65
SONG3 playing: Z | NAME3
SONG2 playing: Y | NAME2
SONG2 playing: Y | NAME2
```

[image]

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed sample of Input_file and expected output so adding this solution now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1 OFS $2]=$NF
  next
}
a[$0]{
  $0=a[$0]
}
1
'  FS='[, ]' file2.txt FS=" " file1.txt
```

While running code following will be output:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1 OFS $2]=$NF
  next
}
a[$0]{
  $0=a[$0]
}
1
'  FS='[, ]' file2.txt FS=" " file1.txt
WWWW
line 45
RRR
EEE
line 24
WWWW
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1 OFS $2]=$NF
  next
}
a[$0]{
  print a[$0]
}
'  FS='[, ]' file2.txt FS=" " file1.txt > temp && mv temp file1.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                   ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2.txt is being read.
  a[$1 OFS $2]=$NF         ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 OFS $2 and value is $NF.
  next                     ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
a[$0]{                     ##Checking condition if a[$0] array a whose index $0 is NOT NULL then do following.
  print a[$0]              ##Printing value of array a with index $0.
}
'  FS='[, ]' file2.txt FS=" " file1.txt > temp && mv temp file1.txt  ##Setting FS as comma OR space for file2.txt AND setting FS as space for file1.txt
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203135/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-in-a-text-file-replace-patterns-with-oth).

Answer (score 0):

> join -t , file1.txt file2.txt

Close! Specify the output format.

```
join -t , -o 2.2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

Remember that input files need to be sorted for `join`. If the files are not sorted we can use process substitution in `bash` to easly sort them on the first field:

```
join -t, -o2.2 <(sort -t, -k1 file1.txt) <(sort -t, -k1 file2.txt)
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DesertedUnlawfulUpgrade).

If you want to preserve the order of the files, then it get's a little bit harder. You have to number the lines, sort on the joining field, join, re-sort on the line numbers and remove line numbers. Let's preserve the sorting order of `file2.txt` below:

```
# number lines in file with comma as a separator
nl -w1 -s, file2.txt |
# sort the file on second field
sort -t, -k2 |
# join files on first field from file1.txt, but now on second field from file2
# output only the first and third field from file2.txt
join -11 -22 -t, -o2.1,2.3 <(sort -t, -k1 file1.txt) - |
# re-sort on the initial order from file2.txt
sort -t, -k1 |
# remove the line numbers
cut -d, -f2-
```

Which is not really nice. That's why `awk` solution is usually preferred in non-extreme cases.

> what if there were multiple lines inbetween not present in file2.txt?

`join` outputs the lines that match. Non-matched lines are not outputted by `join`. You can edit the behavior with `-a` or `-e` or `-v` options in `join`.

Comment: That worked in the example's case. But what if there were multiple lines inbetween not present in `file2.txt`? I want them to be ignored and the command to just replace the one specified in `file2.txt`. Your first command gives error about sorting. The second works **but** I want the command to just replace and not "sort" or change the order of the replace terms.

Comment: The non-matched fields are ignored. If you want the order to stay...

Comment: @Kankrus89, Could you please check my solution once too, and lemme know if that helped you?

Comment: Your updated script did not work. It's my fault, I didn't put too much details in it. Now I'll update the post. Ravinder, yes your script did work according to my example but my needs a more complicated.

Comment: Then, as there are already answers to this question, you could consider just posting a new question with all the relevant details. Or not, depending what "more complicated" means... ; )

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @Kankrus89, Thanks for letting know. As KamilCuk mentioned if you could provide more examples near to your actual Input_file we could look into it, ideally you should do that only from starting of question.

Comment: @Kankrus89, Please check my EDIT solution now and lemme know then?